# wanted all the Tabs (Object Tabs like Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Leads etc.,) in the form of images in the home page layout

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Wanted all the Tabs (Object Tabs like Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Leads etc.,) in the form of images in the home page layout. On click of those images the image has to navigate to the respective objects home page. Eg: when user clicks on Account image the Account home page has to appear on screen.

Comment: what have you tried so far to achieve this? Where are you running into problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a visualforce page.  Use apex:image tags and hyperlinks to create the links you want to.

```
<a href="https://cs14.salesforce.com/001/o"><apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.myResourceImage}" title="Accounts" /></a>
```

Similarly you can add for the other tabs too.

Next go to Setup --> Customize --> Home --> Home Page Components.

Click on **New Custom Component** and select **Visualforce Area**.

Choose the Visualforce page you created.  Make sure to choose the option component position as **Wide (Right) Column** Adjust the height as per your needs

Comment: then no need of controllers

Comment: can you give me the full code snippet

Comment: But in preview i am unable to view my image